# Media Queries are not working. How do I solve this

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive, media

So I built a website resembling a template that I found. The website has two grids in it and I want to change the number of columns and rows with media queries to make the website responsive. However, the media queries just refuse to work properly. There are 2 problems: 1) It does what I want but not WHEN I want, 2) It doesn't do anything at all.

```
   @media screen and (max-width:760px) {
   body{
        background-color: green;
       }
   }
```

this, for example, will work, but the color changes only when the screen is at least 600px wide

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  #grid {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr ;
      grid-template-rows: 2fr 2fr 2fr 2fr;
  }
 }
```

This one won't work at all.
Please help, this is so frustrating, I feel dumb

Answer (score 1):

Since you're building upon an existing template you might have an issue with [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Try to override it by putting `!important` at the end of the declarations which aren't working.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:760px) {
   body{
        background-color: green !important;
       }
   }
```

A better way to do this is to use your browser's inspector to find the declaration which is overriding yours and then edit it (if you have access to that code). But the `!important` is a quick solution for now.

Comment: nope, didn't change anything. Also, when I said that I am using a template, I just meant that I am trying to copy from the template. Al of the coding was done by me

Comment: Can I see the original CSS that you're working with? If ```!important``` isn't working its probably because the original declaration is more specific and has ```!important``` appended to it as well.